# In R, write each nested data frame to a CSV

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv, purrr

PROBLEM:

I have data frame of data frames from `purrr` and want to write each nested data frame to a CSV.

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  dataset                   data
    <chr>                 <list>
1     aab    <tibble [681 × 60]>
2     aae <tibble [1,486 × 173]>
3     acm <tibble [3,496 × 139]>
```

That is, I want 3 CSVs from above: one CSV for each tibble under "data".

I prefer tidyverse functions to `lapply` or similar.

POTENTIAL SOLUTION

I think it's gotta be something using `map()` or similar function:

```
df %>% 
  map(~write_csv(data, file=[how to get filename from 'dataset' column?))
```

Comment: I don't have experience with using `map` personally but after reading Hadley's R for Data Science book, I think this may be a case for `map2` since you have two columns to use.

Comment: yea probably! I don't know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `purrr::by_row`, you can access the `dataset` via `.$dataset`:

```
temp <- df %>% by_row(~write.csv(.$data, file = .$dataset))
```

This will save each tibble in a row to a separate file under the name of *dataset*.

Comment: works awesome for my use case! thanks for quick reply!

Comment: UPDATE: use `purrrlyr:by_row()` as it's no longer in `purrr`

Comment: Note that that .$data appears to pass a list of length 1 to the function, which caused an error in the function I was using (write_parquet). Updating to get rid of the list worked for me `temp <- df %>% by_row(~write.csv(.$data[[1]], file = .$dataset))`