# How to write to disk data from each element of nested data frame in R?

Tags: r, purrr

My question is directly related to this one: [In R, write each nested data frame to a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670521/in-r-write-each-nested-data-frame-to-a-csv), but I am not able to get the solution to work and would like to avoid needing to install the extra required package `purrrlyr`.

I need to write each element (data.frame) of a nested data.frame to a table, with the name of each element corresponding to the first column of the nested data.frame:

```
ir <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest() 
ir$Species <- as.character(ir$Species)

A tibble: 3 x 2

Species    data             
  <chr>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>
```

I tried the linked solution:

```
temp <- ir %>% purrrlyr::by_row(~write.csv(.$data, file = .$Species))
```

But receive the following error:

```
Error in by_row(., ~write.csv(.$data, file = .$Species)) : 
  STRING_PTR() can only be applied to a 'character', not a 'list'
```

I have read about `purrr::walk` but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(ir$data, ir$Species, ~ write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

---

If we don't want the NULL output message on console, use `iwalk`

```
iwalk(setNames(ir$data, ir$Species), ~ write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

Comment: Can you explain the `setNames()` piece? I'd like to use iwalk() as last step in a pipe %>% but can't figure it out. In other words, I don't want to have extra object `ir`

Comment: @Paul If there is a named `list` , the `.y` will be the name of that list.  If there is no names, then it will be the sequence of that list.  So, I named it

Comment: May I expand this a bit? I tried to specify the column containing the nested data for write-out, but couldn't pass the column name to `map2()`. I tried `write_nested_csv <- function(df, col) {df %>% map2(.${{ col }}, .$Species, ~ write.csv(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))}`, but it didn't work in `write_nested_csv(ir, data)`. I got an "Error: unexpected '{'" message.