# writing excel sheet with multiple sheetNames out of nested tibble with purrr

Tags: r, purrr, tibble

how could I write multiple excel sheets into one excel file out of a nested tibble with purrr? 
The nested tibble looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  sheetName data            
  <chr>     <list>          
1 Sheet1    <tibble [4 x 2]>
2 Sheet2    <tibble [4 x 2]>
3 Sheet3    <tibble [4 x 2]>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670521/in-r-write-each-nested-data-frame-to-a-csv

Answer (score 1):

Create a named list of dataframes and use it with `openxlsx` or  `writexl` package.

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(setNames(df$data, df$sheetName), 'temp.xlsx')

writexl::write_xlsx(setNames(df$data, df$sheetName), 'temp1.xlsx')
```